# Making a Grails domain class with JS Objects inside?

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I'm wondering how I would create a Grails domain class with JavaScript objects as variables on the inside of the class.

For example, I am sending a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
   "name":"task",
    "type":{
       "label":"Work",
       "id":1
    },
    "priority":{
       "label":"Mid Priority",
       "id":2
    },
    "completed":false,
    "comments":"",
    "creator":"user",
    "assignedTo":"user"
}
```

As you can see, "type" and "priority" are objects in their own. My grails domain class looks like this currently:

```
package server

class Item {

   //String username
   String name
   String type
   String priority
   boolean completed = false
   String comments
   String creator
   String assignedTo

   static constraints = {
       name nullable: false
       priority nullable: true
       type nullable: true
       comments nullable: true
       creator nullable: false
       assignedTo nullable: false
   }
}
```

Obviously the string is incorrect, but I don't know what it should be? Right now everything is saved as it should be in the JSON list except for the type and priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SQL DBs no other alternatives other than saving the JSON as a string exist. All solutions have marshalling/unmarshalling at some stage, but the data is still stored as a `TEXT` or `BLOB` in a table.

NoSQL DB-s like mongo do allow you to store the BSON object as it is.

Comment: So how should I get the ID and Label from these types? Or will I have to implement them on the client side in a completely different manner?

Comment: it depends. what do you want to store for the `type` field? the label? the id?

Comment: I just ended up changing the types in my client side stuff to strings and working like that.

Comment: "For the SQL DBs no other alternatives other than saving the JSON as a string exist" really? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: I meant common data-types available in Hibernate of course